# Installed Joomla 3.6.2 - Getting Error: The file Cache Storage is not supported on this platform

Tags: joomla-3.x, cache-handler

Issue:

Fresh install of Joomla 3.6.2 on Oracle Linux 7.2.  Error displayed when attempting to load the site or admin area is " The file Cache Storage is not supported on this platform."

Setup:

I have nginx 1.10.1 web server running configured with PHP-FPM 7.0.9.  Apache HTTPD is not installed.  PHP-FPM is running as user nginx:nginx.  MySQL 5.7.14 is also running on a separate server and can be accessed by web server without any issues.  Also note that the Joomla installation did not throw any errors.

What I have tried so far:

I have tried changing ownership of the 'cache', 'tmp' and 'administrator/cache' directories to nginx:nginx.  They are all also world writable (for testing only).  Finally, I have tried changing 'cache_handler' from 'file' to 'cachelite' in the configuration.php file, yet this error persists.

I am not sure what else to try and have not found any other workarounds/solutions to this problem.

Thanks to all in advance.

Shaun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update - this issue has been solved, here are the details.

It turned out this was due to SELinux (shocking, I know).

The thread I used to solve the problem is [here](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=932448)

Thanks and credit go to L0ngN1t3 and Shain Rainville for his excellent [post](http://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/configuring-selinux-policies-for-apache-web-servers/)